# Angular 4 - direct reference to ng-content?

Tags: angular

How to get a **direct reference** (e.g. ElementRef or whatsoever) to a projected ng-content?

**Tried solution:**

```
<ng-content #myRef></ng-content>

// more html markup here
```

Typescript is saying `myRef is undefined`:  I have tried:
@ViewChild('myRef')
@ContentChild('myRef')

**I am not looking for this:**

```
<div #myRef>
    <ng-content><ng-content>
<div>
```

Any solution to my problem?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM in the browser, you'll see there is no `<ng-content>`, therefore there is no way way to get it. "I am not looking for this:" is the workaround

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I have thought so already too.

Comment: with a quick google to what the `ng-content` tag is, i'd suggest using custom components